# Flutter - Grid view, stop scrolling if all items visible on screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a grid view, and I want as follows. When running on a tablet (big screen), since all the items can be seen at once, I want to disable scrolling. However, with a phone, since all the items cannot be seen at once, it needs to be scrollable.

To stop scrolling I use:

```
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

However, I only want this if all the items are visible on the screen. How can I detect this? Or is there another way to achieve what I want.

CODE ADDED:

```
 child: GridView.count(

      // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),

      crossAxisSpacing: 15,
      mainAxisSpacing: 15,
      crossAxisCount: 5,

      children: List.generate(12, (index) {

        double borderWidth = 0;

        if(vehiclesList[index].isSelected){
          borderWidth = 6;
        }else{
          borderWidth = 1;
        }

        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: (){
            // print('2124: ${vehiclesList[index].name} tapped');
            if(vehiclesList[index].isSelected){
              vehiclesList[index].isSelected = false;

              // get index of item to delete:
              int indexToDelete = 0;

              for(var i = 0; i < selectedItemsList.length; i++){
                if(selectedItemsList[i].name == vehiclesList[index].name){
                  indexToDelete = i;
                }
              }
              selectedItemsList.removeAt(indexToDelete);

            }else{
              vehiclesList[index].isSelected = true;
              selectedItemsList.add(vehiclesList[index]);
            }
            setState(() {

            });
          },
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              border: Border.all(
               width: borderWidth,
                color: Colors.purple
              ),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
              child: Center(
                  child: Image(
                  image: AssetImage(vehiclesList[index].imageAsset),

                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }),
    ),
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you add sample code of it.? are you using Gridview.count or something ?

Comment: Code added. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

put this code after the `Widget build(BuildContext context)`

// The equivalent of the "smallestWidth" qualifier on Android.

```
var shortestSide = MediaQuery.of(context).size.shortestSide;
```

// Determine if we should use mobile layout or not, 600 here is
// a common breakpoint for a typical 7-inch tablet.

```
final bool useMobileLayout = shortestSide < 600;
```

so you can do like this

```
physics:useMobileLayout? NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(): scrolling...,
```